# Copying the database through the code

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a database that I connect as a file, i.e. through the AttachDBFile attribute in ConnectionString in web.config file of ASP.NET site. The database is in the App_Data folder od the website. I made a small app, that should allow to copy paste (a kind of backup functionality) the database to any chosen directory. For this I am using FileDialog box for allowing the user to chose the destination directory. I am using the .NET FileSystem API for copy pasting. The problem is that, I cannot copy paste the database till I shut down the SQL Express service. During copy, a dialog saying that the file is currently under use by other process is shown. If I turn off the service I can copy paste the database.

I used AttachDBFile attribute, since I thought that it will allow such copy, since this doesnt directly attach the database to the server. But now I think its not like that. :(

So how I can deal with this. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error since the file is locked while it's in use.

Have a look at the recommended ways to backup your database at msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx.